# Running scrapers in threads in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a couple of scrapers in my Ruby on Rails application and I'm trying to run my data scrapers into separate threads. 
The problem is that my scrapers are storing in `app/controllers/services/scrapers` folder and I can't access this services inside of my thread. Look at the code below:

```
    threads = []

    data.each_key do |office|
      threads << Thread.new(office, data) do |office1, data1|
        data1[office1].each_key do |link|
          if (first condition)
            Services::Scrapers::FirstScraperService.new.parse(link, data1[office1][link])
          elsif (second condition)                      
            Services::Scrapers::SecondScraperService.new.parse(link, data1[office1][link])  
          end         
        end
      end
    end
    threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

Then I got a error: `uninitialized constant ParserController::Services`
If I run scrapers without threads, they working fine.

What ideas or better solutions of my problem can be(I need to run my scrapers in parallel)?

#### Update

My directory structure:

```
 app/controllers/services/scrapers
```

Comment: Can you post your directoy structure? Most probably this issue can be fixed by using `::Services::..`. Give it a try.

Comment: @AkshayGoyal I've uploaded the structure

Comment: Using `::` in front of `Services::Scrapers::FirstScraperService` isn't working?

Comment: @AkshayGoyal I've tried, but getting another problem `warning already initialized constant Services` and `warning: previous definition of Servicies was here`